# How to create a stacked bar in pandas when the group values aren't uniquely identified

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

This question may seem easy but I haven't seen this anywhere and since I am new to python I don't know how to approach this.

I am trying to plot a stacked bar chart from this dataframe:

```
 A   R
208  1
208  5
208  2
210  9
213  5
213  8
213  6
213  3
213  3
215  6
222  4
```

I tried using the following code:

```
df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df['R'].plot.bar(legend=True, stacked=True)
```

Which resulted in[image: Chart1]

But I want the same values on the x-axis to be stacked like this:
[image: Chart2]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This can't be done without transforming the dataframe to a wide format, which can only be done if each value `'R'` in group `'A'`, is assigned an identifier
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample dataframe
data = {'A': [208, 208, 208, 210, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 215, 222], 
        'R': [1, 5, 2, 9, 5, 8, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index='A')

# create a new column adding a unique identifier
df = df.assign(cols=df.groupby(level='A').cumcount())

# display(df)
     R  cols
A           
208  1     0
208  5     1
208  2     2
210  9     0
213  5     0
213  8     1
213  6     2
213  3     3
213  3     4
215  6     0
222  4     0

# pivot the dataframe into a wide form which easily plots
dfp = df.pivot(columns='cols', values='R')

# display(dfp)
cols    0    1    2    3    4
A                            
208   1.0  5.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
210   9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
213   5.0  8.0  6.0  3.0  3.0
215   6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
222   4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

# plot 
ax = dfp.plot.bar(stacked=True, legend=False, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it what you expect?